# jQuery Masonry dynamic header width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

So I'm trying to make a header that re-sizes to the current width of jQuery Masonry grid.

My working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/hGnLH/

I'm trying to accomplish a similar affect to this site: http://citizenmag.citizenm.com/ (I want the header to only be as wide as the Masonry grid, and re-size when a user changes browser width)

Any help / suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I tweaked your fiddle a bit to hook the same width calculations you are making to the jQuery `$(window).resize` event, take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hGnLH/1/). It sets the width of the header to the  `#inner` div's width, although this width is not the same as masonry columns themselves. At least you have a starting point :P

Comment: @scumah Thanks, one step closer. Now I just need to figure out how to get the current width of the Masonry grid and have the header re-size to that width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that complex after all. Take a look at [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/hGnLH/3/) of your fiddle.

Here's the relevant JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#inner").masonry({
        columnWidth: 230,
        gutterWidth: 15,
        isAnimated: true,
        cornerStampSelector: ".corner-stamp"
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var totalColWidth = $("#inner").outerWidth() - 475;
        var columns = parseInt(totalColWidth / 245);

        $("#header").animate({width:(columns*245) + 475},{duration:300, queue:false});

    });
});
```

On windows resize it calculates the width of the "column part", meaning the `#inner` width minus the big image width. With that we can obtain the number of columns by dividing this by the mansonry column width plus the gutter width. Having the column number we can multiply it by 245 (Masonry column width + gutter width) and get the expected header width. We animate the header and we are done.

Comment: thanks again. this is awesome. Thanks for walking me through it.